# Importing a view in xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to use [AndroidQuickResponseCode](https://github.com/phishman3579/android-quick-response-code) in an app I am making. But I have a hard time getting an example to run inside my own app.

I have narrowed down the problem to a reference in a layout file, where it says:

```
<com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView
      android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/transparent">
  </com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView>
```

It goes wrong when it tries to render the com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView in the layout. This it should be able to find in the jar file that I've added as a library. (It finds other files from that jar.) The stacktrace in logcat is rather long, but these lines seem like a summary to me:

```
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): Process: se.tii.vargis, PID: 12552
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.tii.vargis/se.tii.vargis.CaptureActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-23 11:22:57.055: E/AndroidRuntime(12552): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04000d
```

It seems to means that it can't find the com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView that is written in the xml layout file. Is there any special way on importing something so that it can be used in an xml file?

My Activity code is empty, it only sets the layout with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);`

Comment: i think its not getting this class com.jwetherell.quick_response_code.ViewfinderView

Comment: Yes I agree, but I wonder how you should do such a thing. I copied the xml from the example in the project, and in there it works. So it seems to go wrong when trying to reach the class from another project.

Comment: Yes I added the library. If I make a copy of that into my own project, I run into other problems. Are you sure it is not possible to reference to something in a library?

Comment: see my answer @Niels

Answer (score 0):

See you have to make a class in your project same as 
 https://github.com/phishman3579/android-quick-response-code/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/quick_response_code/ViewfinderView.java

and then in xml file you have to give the path of that file as your package name is "com.example.SampleHello" + your class name "ViewfinderView" so your xml will be like this

```
<com.example.SampleHello.ViewfinderView
  android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/transparent">
</com.example.SampleHello.ViewfinderView>
```

Take mouse pointer to the ViewfinderView and click ctrl + click then ViewfinderView class open means it is getting class

Comment: If I do this that part works, but I run into other problems. So I was wondering if it would be possible to reference to the file from the library.

Comment: you dont need to add the library only copy a single java class and then you get some error then solve it

Comment: I'm importing that library anyway for the rest of its code. And I think it would be weird if you can import classes in java code, but not in xml code. But I've never done such things before so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: if you don't need of whole project and still you are adding it then it is waste of memory and it will complicate the code also. and its your wish how you wanna to go

Comment: But I *do* need that whole project, because I'm using all the code from that library

Comment: then you can import whole library

Comment: Yes I do import the library. But like I write above, the xml seems to not be able to find classes from that library. Is there some special way to do this in xml?

Comment: see what you have to do...you already downloaded that code after that import that sample in eclipse and run it. it will show so much error solve it. it is as the sample code. but if you want to add this project as library to your code then add as library and in your layout file do as did in this xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95931/discussion-between-aashvi-and-niels).